# How can you extract data from a pivot table using DGET function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im having this difficulty with the following pivot table where I want to use the `=DGET` function to extract all the names of the students who passed the exams in 2019 and make a list out of it.
As you can see in Cell G81 I tried putting the function `=DGET(A74:D157;"1";F81)` but unfortunately I'm afraid im not referencing it right. Is it possible to use `=DGET` on pivot table and pull info's based on two criteria?

[image]

Comment: I would simply add another pivottable and filter it accordingly.

Comment: I've been thinking the same but unfortunately I have to use the database function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer is **NO**, as `DGET` function can only return single value, and it will throw a #NUM error if more than one record matches criteria.

Judging from your pivot table, I believe you have a source table that contains the names of students who have passed the exam in 2018 and 2019. There are multiple ways to find a list of name from that source table using formula or use another pivot table (which is quicker).